# How to count number of specific element in a repeating set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have infinite set composed of some finite elements a, b, c, d. So the set would be a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, c2, d2, ..., an, bn, cn, dn. How to get the count of single element given the total set count? I figured out how to count number of 'a's: (n-1)/4+1 (n is total set count) but I'm struggling to get the formula for b, c and d.

Comment: How is the set infinite if it has a count of $n$?  The example you gave suggests that the number of $a's$, $b's$, etc. are all the same.  Did you mean to have examples like $\{a,b,c,d,a,b\}$?

Comment: Sorry I wasnt at all clear. Yes the set can have any number of elements so there will be a situation where cycle cuts off before d

Comment: But then your formula doesn't work.  For $n=6$, say, you have the example I wrote, $\{a,b,c,d,a,b\}$.  Your formula gives $\frac 54 +1$ which isn't an integer.  I'll post a solution below...but I am not sure I have understood the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand this, the block $\{a,b,c,d\}$ gets repeated some number of times and may be followed by a truncated block.  Thus, for $n=11$, say, you'd have $$\{a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,a,b,c\}$$
Assuming I have that right, then the total number of completed blocks is given by the greatest integer $\lfloor \frac n4\rfloor$.  The truncated block adds $1$, or fails to add $1$, depending on the remainder of $\frac n4$.  Letting the remainder be $r$ (so $r\in \{0,1,2,3\}$) we have:

Number of $a's$:  $\lfloor \frac n4\rfloor \;if\; r=0\;\& \;\lfloor \frac n4 \rfloor+1 \;if\; r>0$

Number of $b's$:  $\lfloor \frac n4\rfloor \;if\; r=0,1\;\& \;\lfloor \frac n4 \rfloor+1 \;if\; r=2,3$

Number of $c's$:  $\lfloor \frac n4\rfloor \;if\; r=0,1,2\;\& \;\lfloor \frac n4 \rfloor+1 \;if\; r=3$

Number of $d's$:  $\lfloor \frac n4\rfloor$